# Is there a hotkey in Eclipse to "Open declared type"?

Tags: eclipse, hotkeys

When hovering over a variable, one can go straight to its definition pressing F3. But what I'm looking for is for a way to go directly to its type definition, which I'm currently doing by pressing CTRL + clicking "Open declared type".

Is there a easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

- Assign a key stroke for 'Navigate > Open Hyperlink' command via 'Preferences > Keys'. (I use F6)
- Now you can use this key stroke instead of using Ctrl+Click to bring up the hyperlink popup.

Not exactly what you are looking for, but this is the best solution I think.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option, using Ctrl+Shift+t.  This opens a window where you can look up any type you wish.  This becomes a shortcut when you highlight your target, press Ctrl+Shift+t and hit enter.  Imho Ctrl+Click is still faster.

If you would like to check any other shortcuts bind keys go to Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Keys

Comment: I already know CTRL SHIFT T. That would assume I know the type of the variable I'm wanting to go into.. besides that, faster than that would be to do F3 on the variable and then CTRL + LEFT twice and F3 again.

Answer (score 0):

I've always relied on a combination of ctrl+shift+t and the hover options. I never thought of the key stroke assignment. I might try mapping a scroll button click, like opening a link in a new tab.

Answer (score -1):

in `Windows > Preferences > Keys`
search for **Go to Type** and assign it a `ctrl-f3` or `shift-f3` (there is a conflict with `ctrl-f3`)